# What is Google "Deep Linking"

Tags: android, google-play, deep-linking

I'm not sure if my app supports deep linking. It was made with Cocos2d for iPhone and I used apportable to port it to android. I know that deep linking had to do with google's indexing, but what's the difference between just "being indexed" and have a "deep link"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, deep links allows you to make your app content available directly into Google search pages. If a user has your app installed in his device and search for a content that you provide through your app, Google will display a button to launch your app.

You can read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/index.html) to know more about it.

Comment: how do I decide what to put on the manifest? Suppose I want to allow only phone numbers to trigger showing the app, what should I put in there?